# How to execute code on file browsing select?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

[edit: answer below seems to be right, but how can I run ruby code from there?]

I am working on a Rails 3 page for resume submission. How can I make it so that when a resume is selected from the Browse... button, code can be executed? I have been researching this but have not been able to find the same situation.

The field on the page looks something like:

Resume

[text box here to show filename once file is selected] [Browse Button]

And here is the current code. Thanks ahead of time!

```
<label>Resume</label>
  <%= f.file_field :resume %>
  <div class="filedrag">
  <input type ="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this.
Use the change event on the file input.
**edit to see changes**

```
$("#fileselect").change(function() {
  <% @objects.each do |obj| %>
    $("#<%= obj.id %>").attr("style", "<%= obj.style %>");
  <% end %>
});
```

Comment: If the javascript is placed inside your .erb files, it's just a matter of placing erb tags inside the script.